# symfony2 php codesniffer standard error

Tags: eclipse, symfony, phpcodesniffer

I'm new to `phpCodeSniffer` and I'm trying to integrate it with *eclipse*. I've downloaded `phpCodeSniffer` from *PEAR* following [these instructions](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer), and I also downloaded *Symfony2 standards* from [Github](https://github.com/opensky/Symfony2-coding-standard) and the [php-cs-fixer](https://github.com/fabpot/PHP-CS-Fixer). I followed all the instructions and everything works fine, but when I try to use the sniffer with eclipse I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/php -c /tmp/zend_debug/session7507717624755069136.tmp -d asp_tags=off -d short_open_tag=on /opt/eclipse/plugins/org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.tools.codesniffer_1.3.0.R20111119000000/php/tools/phpcs.php --report=xml --standard=/usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards/Symfony2 --tab-width=4 /var/www/siga-nuevo/src/Siga/UserBundle/Controller/UserController.php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PHP_CodeSniffer_Exception' with message 'Referenced sniff Symfony2.Commenting.FunctionComment.MissingParamComment does not exist' in /opt/eclipse/plugins/org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.library.pear_1.2.2.R20120127000000/php/library/PEAR/PHP/CodeSniffer.php:814
Stack trace:
0 /opt/eclipse/plugins/org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.library.pear_1.2.2.R20120127000000/php/library/PEAR/PHP/CodeSniffer.php(730): PHP_CodeSniffer->_expandRulesetReference(Object(SimpleXMLElement))
1 /opt/eclipse/plugins/org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.library.pear_1.2.2.R20120127000000/php/library/PEAR/PHP/CodeSniffer.php(623): PHP_CodeSniffer->getSniffFiles('/usr/share/php/...', 'Symfony2')
2 /opt/eclipse/plugins/org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.library.pear_1.2.2.R20120127000000/php/library/PEAR/PHP/CodeSniffer.php(438): PHP_CodeSniffer->setTokenListeners('/usr/share/php/...', Array)
3 /opt/eclipse/plugins/org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.library.pear_1.2.2.R20120127000000/php/library/PEAR/PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php(551): PHP_CodeSniffer->process(Array, '/usr/ in /opt/eclipse/plugins/org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.library.pear_1.2.2.R20120127000000/php/library/PEAR/PHP/CodeSniffer.php on line 814
```

This is my eclipse *configuration*:

[image: configuration]

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the OpenSky symfony2 standards are broken in your case. The relevant part of the error message is this one:

```
Uncaught exception 'PHP_CodeSniffer_Exception' with message 'Referenced sniff Symfony2.Commenting.FunctionComment.MissingParamComment does not exist'
```

As symfony follows all the current [PSR standards](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards) - namely the `PSR-0`, `PSR-1`, `PSR-2` and `PSR-3` (of which PSR-3 provides just the logger interface which `monolog` respects).

You can aswell directly use the [PSR-2](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/tree/master/CodeSniffer/Standards/PSR2) standard included with newer Versions of PHPCS.

The PSR-2 standard implementation in PHPCS has been updated recently - opposite to those old symfony2 standards. Which means the implementation should be more accurate anyway.